# fatal error C1001: internal compiler error when trying to install scikit-bio on python v3.10.11 (windows 10)

Tags: python, conda, visual-studio-2022, scikits, c1001

I am trying to install the scikit-bio package into my conda environment that uses python v 3.10.11, but I am receiving the fatal error C1001: internal compiler error.  I have installed microscoft visual studio 2022 build tools as it instructed me.

```
 skbio/stats/ordination/_cutils.c(2745): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
      skbio/stats/ordination/_cutils.c(3252): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
      (compiler file 'D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\Compiler\CxxFE\sl\p1\c\omp.cpp', line 6484)
       To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
      If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
      Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
       Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-bio
Failed to build scikit-bio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-bio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: According to [that project's issues, they do not support Windows](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/1843#issuecomment-1532251345) at all.